# Extracting minor allele counts in each row in R

Tags: r, count

Trying to extract the minor allele counts in a set of three columns. The counts are just the number of times each allele is seen in each row. I need to extract the lowest number without reporting 0. Some lines have 0 in one of the rows which is not wanted in the final minor count. Instances of equal rows should report the minor count as the equal value.

I have tried having multiple lines of if (true) statements but this is cumbersome and does not solve the issues fully because of the combination of different scenarios.

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame((sample(0:100,50)),(sample(0:100,50)),(sample(0:100,50)))
names(df) <-c("nAA", "nAa", "naa")

# Minor count output
df[1,] <- "31"
df[2,] <- "19"
df[3,] <- "4"
```

I expect a fourth column with the minor count for each row.

Comment: Can you show first few rows of expected output ? I am still not clear what you mean by minor count.

Comment: Ronak, I just updated it with some further insight into my desired outcome.

Comment: For me your first row is `73  77  71` how do you get 31 from it ?

Comment: Make sure you are using the set.seed(100) function because I am sure this is correct on my end.

Comment: I too used `set.seed(100)` and the first rows are `73 77 71`. Regardless, I'm curious about the generated row values at your end. Did you get a different row values @ConnorMurray?

Comment: Strange that the set.seed(100) is weird on my end, I keep getting the same numbers but you are all reporting different samples. Anyways, the actual outcome is not important because this is an example. For your first row, I would want 71 as the minor count and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` and select there with `x[x>0]` mimimum from counts lager 0 and with `which` you get the column where it is:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) min(x[x>0])) #will give you the minimum
apply(df, 1, function(x) which(x==min(x[x>0]))) #will give you the column of the minumum
```

Comment: I do not think the second line of code is working properly, it is giving me a strange output. This is the first row.    c(nAA = 1, mac = 4)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this code. Here the function `pmin` give you the parallel min of a set of vectors (in this case, the 3 varaibles on your data frame).

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, min = pmin(nAA, nAa, naa))
```